# In Deathly Hallows, did the Weasleys go into hiding?

Tags: harry-potter, ministry-of-magic

I don't know if this is in the books, but it has always not made sense to me. During the war, shouldn't the Weasleys have gone underground because Arthur was stamped a blood traitor in Umbridge's records in her office? Or did Arthur Weasley continue to work at the Ministry along with Kingsley, Tonks, and Lupin? (Or did those three even work at the Ministry?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  I've edited your question to include a more descriptive title, fix a minor grammatical error, and remove some extraneous content.  You can roll back my edit if you prefer - but please then edit it yourself so that the title summarizes what you are asking about.  (We get a *lot* of questions about Harry Potter books.)

Comment: Lupin never worked for the Ministry, by the way; as a werewolf, it was hard for him to find work at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## They continued to work, but later were forced into hiding.

Mr. Weasley continued to work at the Ministry even after it was taken over by Death Eaters and mainly being used to serve the Dark Lord.

> “Ron nodded his appreciation of this news. They had agreed that it was far too dangerous to try to communicate with Mr Weasley while he walked in and out of the Ministry, because he was always surrounded by other Ministry workers. It was, however, reassuring to catch these glimpses of him, even if he did look very strained and anxious.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 12 (Magic is Might)*</sup></sub>

He seemed to be using his position to try and resist the Dark Lord’s ideas from within the Ministry.

> “So, Dirk Cresswell is ten times the wizard you are,’ said Mr Weasley quietly, as the lift sank ever lower. ‘And if he survives Azkaban, you’ll have to answer to him, not to mention his wife, his sons and his friends –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 13 (The Muggle-Born Registration Commission)*</sup></sub>

However, once the Death Eaters knew Ron was helping Harry, the whole Weasley family had to go into hiding, and Arthur had to stop working at the Ministry.

> “He looked round and saw Harry standing there.
> ‘I’ve been getting them all out of The Burrow,’ he explained. ‘Moved them to Muriel’s. The Death Eaters know Ron’s with you now, they’re bound to target the family – don’t apologise,’ he added, at the sight of Harry’s expression. ‘It was always a matter of time, Dad’s been saying so for months. We’re the biggest blood traitor family there is.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 24 (The Wandmaker)*</sup></sub>

Once they went into hiding, none of them could go to work.

> “Harry felt responsible: it was, after all, he who had insisted that the goblin remain at Shell Cottage so that he could question him; his fault that the whole Weasley family had been driven into hiding, that Bill, Fred, George and Mr Weasley could no longer work.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 24 (The Wandmaker)*</sup></sub>

They were able to hide Ginny, because although Hogwarts attendance became compulsory under the Dark Lord’s reign, they went into hiding during the Easter holidays so she was at home.

Comment: You interpreted the question slightly differently than I did when I gave it a descriptive title.  Your interpretation is probably more accurate, so I've updated the title again with that in mind.

Comment: I suspect Arthur stayed at his job mainly to avoid (or at least postpone) the inconvenience and risk of going into hiding - not just for himself, of course, but for his entire family.  Quitting the Ministry would, I suspect, have been considered an act of treachery.  Percy implied as much, if I remember rightly, just before the Battle of Hogwarts.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks a lot! :) I’m trying my best to answer the question, whatever it may actually be - I found it a bit confusing too. That’s an excellent point, he might have been staying in the Ministry at least partly to avoid the difficulties of having him and his family going into hiding.